# SQL query for counting the number of same values in a table and fetching the first value if the count is greater than 1

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table such as

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | status|
+-----+-------+
| 01  | open  |
| 02  | close |
| 03  | close |
| 04  | close |
| 05  | open  |
| 06  | open  |
| 07  | open  |
| 08  | close |
| 09  | open  |
| 10  | close |
+-----+-------+
```

I want the number of open-status records and if the number of records are greater than 1, I want to fetch the 1st open status record ID.

for that, I have been trying doing like this

```
SELECT status, count(*) as count from table_name group by status='open' order by status desc limit 1
if(@count>0)
select * from table_name where status like 'open' union select * from table_name limit 1
```

which seems not working (please forgive me if it is a blunder).

I finally want the ID of the first open-status record if only the number of open status records is more than 1.

Comment: I can't really tell from your code what you want as output so please add it as text and enhance your sample data by adding a third column.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(id), COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE status = 'open'`? or maybe `SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'open' THEN id END), SUM(status = 'open') FROM table`?

Comment: I finally want the ID of the first open-status record if only the number of open status records is more than 1.

Comment: @Aikana 1st one does seem to work but what if IDs are alphanumeric, my actual table contains alphanumerics as ID something like row_id. sorry that I haven't mentioned it in the question.

Comment: *what if IDs are alphanumeric* Use not MIN() but the expression which will return "1st ... record ID" from IDs list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT STATUS, count(*) AS count, MIN(id) AS FirstID
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE STATUS = 'open'
GROUP BY STATUS
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: *`WHERE STATUS = 'open' GROUP BY STATUS`* GROUP BY is obviously excess in this case.